# How to convert a test documents into vector of training vocabulary dimension in weka?

Tags: java, weka

This is really a nasty problem i am facing. I need to create my own classifier in Weka i.e. Rocchio.

Using Weka' StringtoVector functionality i can easily convert training samples into a vector with tf-idf for term weighting and extract a vocabulary of V-dimension, i tried alot but could'nt figure out a way to create a document vector for test document which is V-dimension ( vocabulary from training samples) but i know it is possible like all classifier for which we supply training and test samples seperately would have been done this internally as all need a document vector for test document which is of training-vocabulary dimension but how can i do this in java code so i can get test sample tf-idf vector which is of same dimension as vocabulary and all training samples.

I really appreciate your help in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by:

- Using batch filtering (option `-b` in the command line interface).
- Using a `FilteredClassifier` object, both in command line and in the Explorer.
- Using an `InputMappedClassifier` object, both in the command line and in the explorer.

You can check the full explanation in this blog post: [Mapping Vocabulary from Train to Test Datasets in WEKA Text Classifiers](http://jmgomezhidalgo.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/mapping-vocabulary-from-train-to-test.html).

Comment: Thanx Jose, I am currently doing it with filtered classifier and came to know that filter classifier automatically convert a test instance into a vector having similarly dimension as of training data but what if i implement a new classifier i.e. Rocchio. Would Filtered classifier still do its job of converting the test sample into a vector of similar dimension ?

Comment: If your implementation follows all WEKA conventions, I do not see why it should not work. The `FilteredClassifier` wraps the filter and the classifier, it should properly integrate the `StringToWordVector` filter and your implementation of the Rocchio algorithm, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

you can use batch filter like this:

```
Instances train //from somewhere...
Instances test //from somewhere...

SomeFilter filter = new SomeFilter();
//..set options of the filter..//

//Inform filter about dataset once with the "train" set
filter2.setInputFormat(train);

//useFilter for train, then test set
Instances filteredTrain = Filter.useFilter(train, filter);
Instances filteredTest = Filter.useFilter(test, filter);
```

This way you'll have the same vocabulary  of V-dimension for your test and train set.